# c# com object cant get ref object values

Tags: c#, object, com, marshalling

We are trying to get values returned from a COM object, the function is:

```
bool AxSB100BPC.GetEnrollData(int dwMachineNumber,
int dwEnrollNumber,
int dwEMachineNumber,
int dwBackupNumber,
ref int dwMachinePrivilege,
ref object dwEnrollData,
ref int dwPassWord
```

We are calling this function as:

```
vRet = axSB100BPC1.GetEnrollData(mMachineNumber,
                                 vEnrollNumber,
                                 vEMachineNumber,
                                 vFingerNumber,
                                 ref vPrivilege,
                                 ref oglngEnrollData,
                                 ref glngEnrollPData);
```

The problem is with `oglngEnrollData` which is type of `ref object`. It is declared as `object oglngEnrollData;`.

The error is:

> ```
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
> HResult=-2147352571
> Message=Tür uyuşmazlığı. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
> Source=mscorlib
> ErrorCode=-2147352571
> StackTrace:
>    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,           BindingFlags          flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
>    at SB100BPCLib._DSB100BPC.GetEnrollData(Int32 dwMachineNumber, Int32 dwEnrollNumber, Int32 dwEMachineNumber, Int32 dwBackupNumber, Int32& dwMachinePrivilege, Object& dwEnrollData, Int32& dwPassWord)
>    at AxSB100BPCLib.AxSB100BPC.GetEnrollData(Int32 dwMachineNumber, Int32 dwEnrollNumber, Int32 dwEMachineNumber, Int32 dwBackupNumber, Int32& dwMachinePrivilege, Object& dwEnrollData, Int32& dwPassWord)
>    at enrolldata.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\enrolldata\Form1.cs:line 196
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>    at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>    at enrolldata.Program.Main() in f:\enrolldata\Program.cs:line 19
>    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:
> ```

Any ideas are welcomed

Comment: Crappy manual.  I'd guess at byte[] that's 1416 elements long or an int[] that's 354 elements long.  http://www.secubio.com/upload/file/1292045533.pdf  Call the vendor if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant,  it seems 354 for my case; ` const int DATASIZE = 354; //(1404 + 12) / 4;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/51aaa7c2-baeb-4cd5-991e-67e5c70422de) on another forum seems to be dealing the same problem for the same interface.

This is just a guess based on that thread, but the problem seems to be that the `dwEnrollData` parameter is actually a variant type (not a managed `System.Object` type) in which case you should try using [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.variantwrapper.aspx) to wrap the parameter value you are passing into the method.

Comment: Thank you @mike, tried : `int glngEnrollData;
        object var = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper(glngEnrollData);`, but got : `Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'enrolldata.Form1.glngEnrollData' F:\enrolldata\Form1.cs 28 72 enrolldata`